# Prevent Jquery image tool from running when condition met

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

'm using a jquery tool called [LightBox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). Its a tool for displaying images. It works fine but I need to prevent the lightbox functionality from happening if a certain value is returned from an ajax call. Now, this question is not about the ajax call, its about how do I stop LightBox from doing its thing  after the link has already been clicked?

This is the link that popups the image using LightBox (it works fine)

```
<a id="test_id" href="http://localhost/histogram.do" data-lightbox="histogram1"> Click Me </a>
```

This is my clumsy code to try to stop LightBox from continuing. The alert happens but the lightbox popup still appears right after clicking ok.  Any ideas?

```
$("#test_id").click(function(e){
    alert("hello");
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library uses jQuery .on() to bind the click event to the  element.

Have you tried `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` ?

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

It prevents any other handlers from firing and then calls `stopPropagation()` to prevent bubbling.

Furthermore, to prevent the  element from following the href link on click, you can use `e.preventDefault()`

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: It did stop lightbox from running. But because the anchor was pointing an href address, the actual call to the server still happens. 

So I added this line before your stopImmediatePropagation() so it will not call the server.

$("#test_id").attr("href", "#");

It seems to work, but does that make sense? I'm not a jquery developer so I'm not sure if this is clean or if there is a better way.

Comment: Added to the answer above... You can prevent that call with `preventDefault()`